# TypeError when assigning a random value from a list to a variable?

Tags: python

I have a list and I want to assign a random element from that list to a new variable five times in order to generate a hand of cards. I've searched, and I can't seem to understand why my random.choice is causing errors.

```
import random

cards = { '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' 'J' 'Q' 'K' 'A' }

for newCard in range(5):
        newDraw = random.choice(cards)
        playerdeck.append(newDraw)
        if newDraw in playerdeck:
                playermatches = playermatches + 1
        newDraw = oldDraw
```

When I try to run it I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nathaniel\Desktop\Fcard.py", line 6, in <module>
    newDraw = random.choice(cards)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\random.py", line 253, in choice
    return seq[i]
TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
```

Comment: **The answer that you have accepted doesn't work.**

Comment: @John Machin: I realized that my list wasn't being defined correctly at all. 
cards = [ '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A' ]
This is what I wanted and it is working correctly.

Comment: There are two answers that also pointed out that you didn't have a list and (a) were submitted **before** the one that you chose and (b) did not contain non-working code.

Comment: @John Machin: I'm confused. The answer I chose was submitted first and helped me solve my problem immediately. Isn't that grounds for me to choose it? I didn't realize that my list wasn't defined correctly. That was the root of my problem.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused about the order of the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `{` and `}` rather than `[` and `]` to define `cards`. Therefore, it is a `set`. `set`s are not ordered, and therefore it makes no sense to try to index into it. `random.choice` needs to index into a collection to pull an item out of it. Anyway, a quick fix is to replace this:

```
random.choice(cards)
```

With this:

```
random.choice(list(cards))
```

**Edit:** Also add commas between the elements in the set.

Comment: -1 This won't work. The set has only 1 element. The quickest fix is to remove the braces.

Comment: I feel blind after staring at everything for so long. My list wasn't a list at all! Thank you for pointing that out, I hadn't even realized it.

Answer (score 1):

So use a list:

```
>>> cards = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
>>> random.choice(cards)
'9'
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with your set definition.
When you have multiple strings side by side, python concatenates them as if you did `'A' + 'B'`. So you generated a set with only one element which is `'23456789JQKA'`

You don't really need a set or a list to do that:

```
>>> cards = '23456789JQKA'
>>> random.choice(cards)
```

PS:
Although sets cannot be indexed, they can be iterated:

```
>>> [int(i) for i in {'1','2','3'}]
[1, 3, 2]
```

Note the order may not be preserved.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the set has only one element, and for suggesting a string instead of a list.